# ActionScript, Android and ANE

Tags: java, android, eclipse, actionscript-3, flash

Sorry for my bad english.

I want to make a game for Android platform, but every time when i change my device orientation, the activity is restarted and i loss all data. I had read that i can prevent activity from being restarted by overriding onConfigurationChanged function in Android. The problem is that i make my game in Flash, with AS3 and i don't have access to Android API, therefore i must create an ANE which will handle onConfigurationChanged, but this doesn't work and i don't know why...onConfigurationChanged is not triggered when i change my orientation.

Question is - Is this possible to handle onConfigurationChanged from an ANE?

I work in FlashBuilder for Flash, and Eclipse for Java to make ANE, and there is 2 manifest files in which i can put android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize", one in Flash Builder and one in Eclipse, which of it must contain android:configChanges="orientation|screenSize" ?

I'm novice in android and ANE's and my be i do something wrong.

Answer (score 0):

Are you simply trying to handle the orientation changes? You shouldn't need an ANE for this, have a look at the autoOrients and ORIENTATION_CHANGE event:

http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/StageOrientationEvent.html#ORIENTATION_CHANGE

If your application is restarting it's most likely something slightly amiss in your application descriptor. Just double check that you've got all the defaults in the manifest additions under the android node.

Comment: No, i don't trying to simply handle the orientation changes:) And where i'am saying that my applications is restarted when i change the orientation? I talk about activities in Android :) Activities are restarted not application.

Comment: Can you post your application descriptor? Sounds like a problem there at a guess...